# Как найти максимальный элемент массива В и заменить им минимальный элемент массива А?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

```
A = [[9, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 1]]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,78,0]

max = B[0]
min = A[0][0]

for i in range(len(B)):
    if B[i] > max:
        max = B[i]

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] < min:
            min = A[i][j]

min = max  # здесь хочу присвоить минимальному элементу максимальный, но не получается
for i in A:
    print(i)
```

Comment: min и max - зарезервированные ключевые слова, не используйте из в качестве названий переменных

Comment: как мне переопределить элемент в массиве в итоге?

Comment: по индексу . макс число имеет индекс такойто, по этому индексу и записывать новое значение.

Comment: Запоминайте не только сам максимальный элемент, но его индекс. Потом по этому индексу сможете его заменить.

Comment: переменные я назвал по-другому

Comment: вам нужно сохранить значение и ***индексы элементов***, тогда будет понятно что на что менять

Comment: Добавил переменные

Comment: index_minimum = i,j , index_maximum = i

Comment: Ещё вот в этой конструкции `for j in range(len(A[0])):` по-хорошему надо использовать `A[i]`. А то вдруг длина строк в матрице `A` будет различна.

Comment: minimum[index_minimum] = maximum[index_maximum] и сделал такое выражение,но выдает ошибку

Comment: по заданию длина фиксирована

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [
    [9, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 1]
]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78, 0]

m = min(a, key=min) # ищем по самому маленькому значению
i = a.index(m)      # берём индекс по ряду
j = m.index(min(m)) # берём индекс по колонке

a[i][j] = max(b)    # заменяем на максимальное
```

Comment: python style прекрасен! ps я еще и условие неправильно прочитал ((

Comment: @Jack_oS, укоротил, теперь прекрасно

Comment: `lambda` можно заменить на `min`

Comment: @Danis, da-da..

Answer (score 4):

```
a_list = [
    [9, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 1]
]
b_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78, 0]
```

индекс наибольшего элемента списка `b_list`:

```
index_b_max = b.index(max(b))
```

индекс наименьшего элемента списка списков `a_list`:

```
a_min = a_list[0][0]
index_a_min = 0, 0

for i, sublist in enumerate(a_list):
    for j, el in enumerate(sublist):
        if el < a_min:
            a_min = el
            index_a_min = i, j
```

поменять местами:

```
a_list[index_a_min[0]][index_a_min[1]], b_list[index_b_max] = b_list[index_b_max], a_list[index_a_min[0]][index_a_min[1]]
```

результат:

```
>>> a_list
[[9, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 78]]
>>> b_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0]
```

---

**UPD** сам не знаю, откуда я взял "поменять местами" в условии?..
Просто значение максимального элемента `b_list` записать на место минимального в `a_list`:

```
a_list[index_a_min[0]][index_a_min[1]] = max(b_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Т.к min и max - переменные, они ссылаются на значения, а не на элементы массива. Т.е лучшим решением будет сохранять не не значения, а индексы чисел.

Пример:

```
A = [[9, 2, 3],  # Your arrays
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 1]]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,78,0]


max = 0
min = (0, 0)
for i in range(len(B)):
    if B[i] > B[max]:  # Use index instead of value 
        max = i
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] < A[min[0]][min[1]]:  # Use index instead of value 
            min = (i, j)
A[min[0]][min[1]] = B[max] # Replacing
for i in A:
    print(i)
```

Comment: min и max - встроенные методы языка python. называть так переменные - очень плохая идея.

Comment: имена переменных сохранены из вопроса. изменения оригинального кода минимальны, чтобы афтар понял где была ошибка

Comment: @Интик, было бы хорошо, чтобы ответы не только автору пользу приносили. Поэтому лучше показать сразу как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну и ещё вариант. Нечто среднее между ответом @entithat и @Jack_oS.

```
A = [[9, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 1]]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,78,0]

min_a, r, c = min((el,ri,ci) for ri,row in enumerate(A) for ci,el in enumerate(row))
A[r][c] = max(B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно такой вариант, если нужна только замена без сохранения индексов

```
A = [[9, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 1]]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,78,0]

a_min = min([_ for r in A for _ in r])
b_max = max(B)
A = [[b_max if _ == a_min else _ for _ in r] for r in A]
```

В принципе все можно и в одну строку, но тогда будем на каждом цикле пересчитывать минимумы и максимумы.